# When i import an obj file from Roblox the obj turns into pieces.!

Tags: objects, import, file-format

I am new to blender.

I make Roblox renders such as my profile pic.
but when i import an obj from Roblox the obj turns into pieces can anyone please tell me how to make it whole?

Comment: Did you try selecting the objects and joining them with CTRL+J ?

Comment: i shall try that

Comment: Wow thank you sir..I started using blender yesterday to pursue my hobby of becoming a Professional GFX Artist and when i stumbled into this problem i thought it was the end but you fixed it thanks alot..

Comment: Also how do you unjoin objects?

Comment: Duarte, Next time i make a post i wont add useless text thanks for the  help :)

Comment: Is you profile pic for somewhere else a roblox render?

Comment: uhm my profile pic is a roblox render